# Math: How to spin a wheel by drag&drop (Canvas, 2D)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I'm struggling with probably simple math to spin/rotate a wheel using drag&drop.

There is a Radial Layout in a Canvas (Unity UI) and it can already be rotated by setting a property called StartAngle that is in a range from 0-360. In this Radial there are items, so the StartAngle is for the first item and places all the child elements around the layout radius.

I want to implement drag & drop for the items so that you can drag a child around and the Radial will spin accordingly (infinitely).

Right now, I have this as a starting point:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var delta = eventData.delta.x * Time.deltaTime;
    var newAngle = radialLayout.StartAngle + delta;
    if (newAngle >= 360)
        newAngle = newAngle - 360;
    else if (newAngle < 0)
        newAngle = Mathf.Abs(360 - newAngle);
    radialLayout.StartAngle = newAngle;
}
```

It kind of works but doesn't feel very smooth. This is for mobile/touch, so I want both the X and Y delta of the drag operation to be taken into account. Apparently, the y delta is not considered in my example and I have no idea how to incorporate this correctly. The user might do a linear drag & drop on either axis or he/she might also do like a circular drag movement.

So how can I map mouse movement to a rotation angle from 0-360 so that it feels good?

**Edit: Thanks for the help, I did it like this now:**

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // Note the "Head-Minus-Tale rule for Vector subtraction, see http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/MOW/vectors/vectors-3/v-3-7.html
    //  vSourceToDestination = vDestination - vSource;

    // First, we draw a vector from the center point of the radial to the point where we started dragging
    var from = dragStartPoint - (Vector2)radialLayout.transform.position;
    // Next, we draw a vector from the center point of the radial to the point we are currently dragging on
    var to = eventData.position - (Vector2)radialLayout.transform.position;
    // Now, we calculate the angle between these two: 
    var dragAngle = Vector2.SignedAngle(from, to);

    // Lerping makes movement fast at the beginning slow at the end
    var lerpedAngle = Mathf.Round(Mathf.LerpAngle(radialLayout.StartAngle, dragAngle, 0.5f));
    radialLayout.StartAngle = lerpedAngle;
}
```

Comment: it might heavily confuse the user if the app guesses wrong about how they are trying to interact with the radial menu (spin/linear). Consider picking one way of interacting and code that, or optionally have a boolean that determines how it interprets, and the player can select if they prefer linear or spin interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know all of your code and types but I would have an idea. I can't test this right now and can not garant that it even works like this but I hope the idea gets clear.

---

I would probably rather use something like

```c#
// This is the vector from the center of the object to the mouse/touch position
// (in screen pixel space)
var touchDirection = eventData.position - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
// angle between the Up (Y) axis and this touchDirection
// for the angle the length of the up vector doesn't matter so there is 
// no need to convert it to pixel space
var targetAngle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.up, touchDirection);
// since the returned angle might be negative wrap it to get values 0-360
if(targetAngle < 0) targetAngle += 360;

// Now either simply use Lerp
// this would simply interpolate each frame to the middle of both values
// the result is a fast movement at the beginning and a very slow at the end
radialLayout.StartAngle = Mathf.Lerp(radialLayout.StartAngle, targetAngle, 0.5f);

// or maybe use a fixed speed like 30°/second
var difference = targetAngle - radialLayout.StartAngle;
radialLayout.StartAngle += Mathf.Sign(difference) * Mathf.Min(30f * Time.deltaTime, Mathf.Abs(difference));
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*